# How to implement strict checking getInt() function?

Tags: c

I have written following code to get an integer from keyboard.
It will prompt an Error message until you give a valid integer value (either negative or positive ).

One condition is It has to check every possible test cases

like:

```
-3.2 
5.0
984237.4329
0.343
.434
12344.
adfs34
233adds
3892710492374329
helloIamNotainteger
```

For all of this tests it should fail.It will pass only for `int >=INT_MIN && int <=INT_MAX` 
value.

My Running code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int min=INT_MIN;
int max=INT_MAX;

int main()
{
        char str[50],c; //I have taken size 50 please ignore this 
        int check;
 do
 {
        int flag=1,i=0,j=0,num=0;
        check=0;
        printf("Enter an Integer : ");
        while((c=getchar())!='\n')
                str[i++]=c;
        if(str[0] == '-')
        {
                flag = -1;
                j++;
        }
        for(;j<i;j++)
        {
                if(str[j] >= '0' && str[j] <= '9')
                        num=(str[j]-'0') + num*10;
                else
                        break;

        }
        if(j<i)
        {
          printf("Not an Integer, Please input an integer \n");
        }
        else if(num < min || num >max)
        {
          printf("Integer is out of range,Please input an integer \n");
        }
        else
        {
                num *=flag;
                printf("The given number is : %d\n",num);
                check=1;
        }
 }while(check == 0);
        return 0;

}
```

One example : For values like this.
83429439803248832409 (It's integer but it should fail because of range )but it passes and give some other integer value.

How to solve this within my code or any better idea to implement `getInt()` ?

Comment: how will you check all the conditions in `scanf()` please if you have any idea give me in the answer .. because I tried with `scanf()` then I switched to this method..actually I got stuck there in `scanf()`

Comment: If satisfied definitly upvote and accept your answer

Comment: Can you use `strtol`, rather than reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Kirilenko : I didn't get you at all how will I use `strtol` here in this case

Comment: what is value of min and max

Comment: It's actually the `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` `#defined` in `<limits.h>`.

Comment: I ran a simple code in codepad.org. int i=83429439803248832409; print i; and the output is 310079385.

Comment: @Omkant see the answer below

Comment: @Omkant scanf doesn't detect overflows, so strtoul is the way to go.

Comment: what is this `strtoul` is it typo? I think it should be `strtol`

Comment: @Omkant `strtoul` is for `unsigned` long, sorry typo.

Comment: ohhh... Thanks how can I forgot , yeah it's `ul`

Comment: Trying to fix it out by my self ..

Comment: Please see my answer is that working? I wanted it like that..I just solved it without help of `strtol`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code : please see this , I did that wihtout `strtol` and it satisfies all conditions and takes only `int`

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<limits.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main()
    {
            int num;
            char str[500],c;
            int check;
            char max[12];
            char min[12];
            sprintf(max,"%d",INT_MAX);
            sprintf(min,"%d",INT_MIN);
     do
     {
            int flag=1,i=0,j=0;
            num=0;
            check=0;
            printf("Enter an Integer : ");
            while((c=getchar())!='\n')
                    str[i++]=c;
            str[i]='\0';
            if(str[0] == '-')
            {
                    flag = -1;
                    j++;
            }
            for(;j<i;j++)
            {
                    if(str[j] >= '0' && str[j] <= '9')
                            check = 1;               
                else
                {
                        check = 0;
                        break;
                }

        }
        if(check == 0)
        {
                printf("Not an Integer, Please input an integer \n");
        }
        /************Start of checking integer range **************/
        else
        {
                if( (flag == -1 && (strlen(str) > strlen(min))) || 
                    (flag == 1 && (strlen(str) > strlen(max))) )
                {
                        check = 0;
                        printf("Integer is out of range, \n");
                }
                else if(flag == -1 && (strlen(str) == strlen(min)) )
                {
                        i=0;
                        while(min[i]!='\0')
                        {
                                if (str[i] > min[i])
                                {
                                        check = 0;
                                        printf("Integer is out of range \n");
                                        break;
                                }
                                i++;                        }
                        if(check == 1)
                        {
                                for(j=1;j<strlen(str);j++)
                                        num=(str[j]-'0')+num*10;
                                num *=flag;
                                printf("The given number is : %d\n",num);
                        }
                }

                else if(flag == 1 && (strlen(str) == strlen(max)) )
                {
                        i=0;
                        while(max[i]!='\0')
                        {
                                if (str[i] > max[i])
                                {
                                        check = 0;
                                        printf("Integer is out of range\n");
                                        break;
                                }
                                i++;
                        }
                        if(check == 1)
                        {
                                for(j=0;j<strlen(str);j++)
                                        num=(str[j]-'0')+num*10;
                                num *=flag;
                                printf("The given number is : %d\n",num);
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                for(j=0;j<strlen(str);j++)
                        num=(str[j]-'0')+num*10;
                num *=flag;
                printf("The given number is : %d\n",num);
                }
        }
        /************End of checking integer range ****************/
 }while(check == 0);

return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use standard library functions.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getInt (const char *s)
{
    long int n = strtol (s, NULL, 10);

    if (n < INT_MIN || n > INT_MAX)
        /* handle overflows */
    else
        return (int) n;
}
```

To handle other errors, you can several conditions.

```
#include <errno.h>

int getInt (const char *s, size_t size)
{
    const char *pEnd1 = s + size;
    char *pEnd2;
    long int n;

    errno = 0;

    n = strtol (s, &pEnd2, 10);

    if (n < INT_MIN || n > INT_MAX || errno != 0 || pEnd1 != pEnd2)
        /* error */
    else
        return (int) n;
}
```

Comment: I have implemented .. but it's not that what I wanted It doesn't take care of other things that I have asked in the question .. It goes to else part also

Comment: Why it goes to else please everytime for whatever input I give ?

Comment: The general case of `(n==0) && (error != 0)` is missing in the list of error checks.

Comment: Also I find it notable that is is one of the rare cases where **`error` has to be initialised** prior to calling the function which optionally sets it.

Comment: @alk If you're referring to `errno`, you have to set that to 0 before any call to a function that may set it if you want to check its value afterwards.

Comment: `if (n < INT_MIN || n > INT_MAX)`, this doesn't help anything, because once the integer has overflowed it is most likely back inside the range. In fact, on a normal 2's complement machine, `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]` already covers all the possible values of an `int` and therefore this condition always fails.

Comment: @Shahbaz: `n` is not an `int`, it is a `long int`.

Comment: What if the size of `long int` is the same as `int`? What if it overflows in such a way that it is still in the range of `int`?

Comment: @Shahbaz: If the size of `long int` is the same as `int` and if there is an overflow, then the condition `errno != 0` would be false, because `strtol` sets `errno` with `ERANGE` when there is an overflow/underflow.

Comment: Yes I was referring to `errno`, sry for that typo. @DanielFischer @Kirilenko

Comment: @Kirilenko, right. Then maybe remove the first piece of code because it's a bit misleading.

Comment: @DanielFischer Most calls setting `errno` to a specific value != 0, do indicate by what they return that an error occurred (e.g -1). In such cases one can rely on `errno` having been set. So there is no need to initialise it prior to the call.

Comment: @alk Mm, right. I'm so used to setting it to 0 since 0, `NULL` or `EOF` are legitimate return values for `strtoX`, `fgets` or `fgetc` respectively that I forgot it isn't always necessary.

Comment: Please see my answer is that working. I wanted it like that..I just solved it

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are trying to store a value which is more than 32768 into the integer(not unsigned). So when you do that it will display some garbage value which was present in the storage variable. As you know that integers in c are having memory limits. Like int datatype of unsigned type can store values from 0 - 65535. So trying to store a number more than that will cause issues. If need to store bigger numbers try using long int datatype. Maybe it might help. But that datatype is also having memory restrictions with values close to 4lakh or something.

Hope that helps.

Comment: with long int also it will fail at it's max_range like 65535 for 2 bytes same will fail for longer also...

Comment: i mean to say try making ur `num` variable of type long int and while printing the value in num print it with the control string "%ld". Or else it will show you same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although this would better fit as comment to *Kirilenko* well checking solution, my note would be to long so I'll be posting it at as answer.

The main problem with the converison functions is that it's difficult (`strtol()`) to impossible (`atoi()`) to test whether the conversion did what was expected.

So when trying to make things more reliable (as `atoi()`) and easier to use (as `strtol()`) solutions like *Kirilenko*'s would be used.

Anyhow the approach provided by *Omkant* still suffers the misdesign of not being capable if something went wrong in the conversion (from the callers perspective).

So the interface should better be like that of lots of other system function, that return their outcome as function value:

```
/* 
 * Tryies to convert the first 'size' characters of 's' to an 'int' and optionally 
 * writes it to '*result'.
 * 
 * Returns the number of characters converted or any qualified negative error code
 * on failure.
 */
int getInt(
  const char * s,  /* source string to try to be converted to an integer */
  size_z size, /* number of digits to be converted (shall not be > strlen(s)) */
  int * result /* optional reference to an int to place the conversion result in */
);
```

And, As a notable side effect, by pass `NULL` as last parameter one is capable of simply testing whether the conversion would work, and in addtion one could receive the number of digits the resulting integer would need.

---

To then still be able to use this conversion function as if it was returning its result as a function value, what might be handy in situations, one might like to use the following macro:

```
GETINT(str, size, result, rc) \
  (rc = getInt(str, size, &result), result)
```

Usage:

```
char s[] = "42";
int rc = 0;
int i = GETINT(s, 2, i, rc);
if (rc)
  /* some error */
else
  /* use i */
```

Comment: Please see my answer is that working. I wanted it like that..I just solved it

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to compare them as strings. First of all, note that a 32 bit integer cannot be more than 10 digits (and a sign).

```
int32_t get_int32()
{
    char input[13];
    char check[12];
    int32_t result;

    if (scanf("%12s", input) != 1)
        /* handle error */
    /* ignore rest of number if any */
    ungetc('x', stdin);
    scanf("%*s");

    /* if length is bigger than 11, error */
    if (strlen(input) > 11)
        /* handle error */

    if (sscanf(input, "%"SCNd32, &result) != 1)
        /* handle error */
    sprintf(check, "%"PRId32, result);

    if (strcmp(input, check) != 0)
        /* handle error */

    return result;
}
```

Note that the `strlen` check can be ignored and the `strcmp` will take care of that. Also note that if you get `input` and `check` large enough (say `25`), you can safely use `int` instead of `int32_t` because you'd know that it can't be more than 64 bits (at least for many years).

Comment: You should know that 10 digit numbers are also out of range of int

Comment: @omkant, 1,234,567,890 is a perfectly valid 32 bit integer.

Comment: what about 3,212,373,273... ?

Comment: @omkant, like I said, you can completely ignore that `if`, since the `strcmp` covers all cases. Nevertheless, length of bigger than 10 is always out of range, but length of exactly 10 is not necessarily out of range. That is why you can't reject any number just because it has 10 digits.